No bootable device install
I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 22.04 on my NAS (a Dell PowerEdge R720; a very old server).
I've never had problems installing ubuntu, but for some reason with this server it just don't want to boot. I am using a disk on the RAID controller (the controller is on "IT mode", so kinda like no RAID at all, it can just see all drives) and the disk does show as detected, but it can't boot from it.
With my multiple tries I found that: Ubuntu 22, 20, 18 and 16 doesn't work. Arch 2024 doesn't work. But TrueNAS Scale (latest version) DOES work; it does boot. I also tried to put the efi and /boot partitions on a sepparate USB disk, and it also DOES work (but I don't know why it sometimes bricks the BIOS so I'd like to avoid that).
As right now the better option we have is TrueNAS, I was wondering if someone knows what are the differences between that and Ubuntu...
Here's the fdisk -l output on a fresh TrueNAS install:
Disklabel type: gpt
Device     Size   Type
/dev/sda1  1M     BIOS boot
/dev/sda2  512M   EFI System
/dev/sda3  931G   Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS

Thanks in advance!
Edit (more relevant info):
I think while installing Ubuntu the usb was detected as sda, and I've read that the bootloader sometimes won't install on sdb. Still, I tried to manually install it (plus, when I did install Arch I did it too) so that shouldn't be the issue.

I doubt on this Ubuntu support site anyone will know TrueNAS . Just an FYI for you I run Ubuntu 22.04 on Dell R320 a pair of them. I did install Desktop not server as I wanted to use a desktop app on them.

@DavidDE but with the fdisk output you don't have any clue of why it could be different?

I will try to install ubuntu Desktop, just to be sure...

As David suggested, I tried to install regular Ubuntu 22.04 instead of the server variant, and it works...
The partitions created for both Ubuntu and Ubunut server are the same, so I assume it's a driver issue?... Whatever, it works now.
